# What does Authorize(Users="*") mean?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I saw this in an ASP.NET MVC 2 app and I can't figure out what it means by looking at the MSDN help.

```
[Authorize(Users="*")]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
...
}
```

The * is throwing me.

Comment: I would guess it's a wildcard to mean authorize any user, but I don't know ASP.NET-MVC well enough to say for certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The asterisk is a wildcard which means "all".

Comment: So this is saying all authorized users are allowed to run the Edit action?  What about just Authorize(Users="").  I thought that meant all users are allowed to run the Edit action.  Still confused.

Comment: @mpenrow - that would only authorise users who had no name.

Answer (score 2):

It actually allows only the users that have the username equal to "*".
The same thing happens to [Authorize(Users="?")]. It autorizes only the users that have "?" as the username.

These values are not interpreted as regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

It's mean ALL.

see for more infos about `regular expressions`:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression